# Windows Daylight Saving Time (DST) and Windows Time Zone problem solving

Tags: windows-xp

OS: WinXP SP3

I've read this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/windows_time_zones_and_dst) and installed [MSXML6](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=993c0bcf-3bcf-4009-be21-27e85e1857b1) (msxml6.exe) and [Powershell 2.0](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Windows-PowerShell.shtml) (WindowsXP-KB968930-x86-ENG.exe). But I still got error when running 'Mats_Run.TimeZones.exe' when attempting to fix the DST issue.

The error message is:
[image]

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, and got a powershell error message when trying to run Mats_run_timezones.exe and I fixed it by installing the following hotfix KB955839
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21764

hopefully this will help some others as there really is no information on this problem coming up in a google search.